# SocialDataService.asmx deprecated in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, social-comment

Im trying to get commentscount on url using the CountCommentsOnUrl

Now im getting this error when using SocialDataService.asmx:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> This service operation is deprecated, you should remove the call by October 15th 2014